# PostgreSQL: No function matches the given name and argument types. Weekly user login cohort analysis

Tags: sql, postgresql

> function sum(boolean) does not exist LINE 13: ISNULL(SUM(s.Offset =
> 0), 0) w1, ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument
> types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I'm trying to create a weekly cohort analysis that would show the weekly login stats.
As you can see this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

This is what I have found, and what I'm trying to re-create:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/172dbe/1

[image]

These are the tables that I'm trying to take the data for:

[image]

[image]

And this is what I have refactored so far:

```
SELECT
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(tb.cohort, ' Monday'), '%X-%V %W') as date,
size,
w1,
w2,
w3,
w4,
w5,
w6,
w7
FROM (
  SELECT u.cohort, 
    ISNULL(SUM(s.Offset = 0), 0) w1,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.Offset = 1), 0) w2,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.Offset = 2), 0) w3,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.Offset = 3), 0) w4,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.Offset = 4), 0) w5,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.Offset = 5), 0) w6,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.Offset = 6), 0) w7
  FROM (
   SELECT
      id,
      last_login AS cohort
    FROM users_user
  ) as u
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
      login_log.user_id,
      DATE_PART('day',(users_user.last_login - users_user.date_joined)/7) AS Offset
      FROM users_userloginlog login_log
      LEFT JOIN users_user ON (users_user.id = login_log.user_id)
  ) as s ON s.user_id = u.id
  GROUP BY u.cohort
) as tb
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(AddedDate, "%Y-%u") dt, COUNT(*) size FROM users GROUP BY dt
) size ON tb.cohort = size.dt
```

Comment: `str_to_date()` and `date_format()` are not Postgres functions. Are you sure you are using Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message tells you: you can't sum boolean values. And `s.Offset = 0` returns `true` or `false` (or `null`). What would be the "sum" of `true, false, true, true, false`?

You can achieve what you want using filtered aggregation:

```
  SELECT u.cohort, 
         count(*) filter (where s.Offset = 0 as w1,
         count(*) filter (where s.Offset = 1) as w2,
         count(*) filter (where s.Offset = 2) as w3,
         count(*) filter (where s.Offset = 3) as w4,
         count(*) filter (where s.Offset = 4) as w5,
         count(*) filter (where s.Offset = 5) as w6,
         count(*) filter (where s.Offset = 6) as w7,    
   ....
```

Comment: Hey, can we continue in the chat?